# Using either MySQL or NoSQL for user defined fields

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I am building a PHP application that is largely a relational concept (one to many relationships) and where 90% of the fields/columns are predetermined.  This sounds perfect for a MySQL database.  My hang-up is that I need to allow the user to define just a handful of fields so that the application can suit the users need.

I am going back and forth between MySQL and nosql (MongoDB to be specific) but I would hate to move the entire application to mongodb when all I need is about 10 user define fields in my table.  Yes, if I move to nosql then I have the ability for each user to have their own schema but then I lose the ability to join tables which opens another world of problems.  Embedding documents is only recommended if the embedded document is of manageable size and in my case it is not.  Also my entire application is relational so even if I embedded one document that doesn't fix the problem when I have to link to another collection.

I guess my question is, does anyone know of a simple MySQL way to allow users to add 5-10 custom fields/columns that would be searchable and sortable.  This would be limited to 5-10 fields in an effort to prevent my schema for exploding in the future with unlimited user defined fields (as stated in many articles on EAV models).

I know there are some articles on stack but many of them are 2009-2011 so I just wanted to see if there are any new solutions/models. If I have to go the nosql/mongo route my next post will be about how to construct a table from two collections using reference (like a left join).

Comment: can you not use both?

Comment: I would hate to manage both.  Also because my app is largely relational how would i then join the mysql tables with the nosql tables to create reports?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information about the user determined fields, like data type, size, # of fields for each user, etc.

Since you already mentioned that 90% of the fields are predefined, I think MySQL still suits you needs better. Perhaps try storing those user defined data in a separate table, let's call it `user_defined_fields`.

This `user_defined_fields` table should have 4 columns (more if necessary):

- `id`: database default primary key (not really necessary)
- `user_id`: which user the row belongs to, pointing to the original `users` table
- `attr_name`: name of field
- `attr_value`: arbitrary data for that field

Add a unique index for `(user_id, attr_name)`.
Add more indexes to make it easier for different ways of query.

Then you can join as usual, to get predefined info and all user-defined data of a particular user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  So i get your model save the udf information in a separate table.  My next question is then where do I actually store the data from the udf.  For example i have a contacts table with the usual fields name, phone, etc? Then another table holding attributes of the user define fields for contacts.  Do i add columns to the contacts table ud1, ud2, and save the data all in the contacts table? or do i save it in another table called user define results and join the user define results to contact results ?